# How do you use Jackson to convert a Java Map to a composed POJO?

Tags: java, json, jackson-databind, netflix, conductor

I've been experimenting with more reliable ways to parse inputs from a Conductor workflow. To do this, I've created a composed class structure with a person and their vehicles.

**Person.java**

```
public class Person {

    protected String firstName;
    protected String lastName;
    protected List<Vehicle> vehicles;

    // Constructors, getters, setters

}
```

**Vehicle.java**

```
public class Vehicle {

    public String make;
    public String model;
    public String trim;
    public short year;

    // Constructors, getters, setters

}
```

I then created a worker which uses Jackson to convert Conductor Client's `Task.getInputData()` Map to the above POJOs.

**ExperimentalStepWorker.java**

```
public class ExperimentStepWorker implements Worker {

    protected ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // Other @Overloaded methods per the Worker interface

    /**
     * Executes a task and returns the updated task.
     *
     * @param task Task to be executed.
     * @return the {@link TaskResult} object
     * If the task is not completed yet, return with the status as IN_PROGRESS.
     */
    @Override
    public TaskResult execute(Task task) {

        TaskResult result = new TaskResult(task);

        Person person = objectMapper.convertValue(task.getInputData(), Person.class);

        System.out.println("The map's contents were:");
        System.out.println(task.getInputData());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The objects's contents were:");
        System.out.println(person);

        result.setStatus(TaskResult.Status.COMPLETED);

        return result;
    }
}
```

I then submitted the following workflow to Conductor. The first one has no inputs. The second has only a Person object, and the last and final one has an array of three vehicles:

**Workflow input from Postman to Conductor Server**

```
{
    "name": "see_if_jackson_works",
    "workflowDef": {
        "ownerApp": "postman",
        "createdBy": "postman_user",
        "name": "do_all_the_things_2",
        "description": "Test Http Task Workflow",
        "version": 1,
        "tasks": [
            {
                "name": "worker_1",
                "taskReferenceName": "First Experiment",
                "inputParameters": {},
                "type": "SIMPLE",
                "startDelay": 15,
                "optional": false
            },
            {
                "name": "worker_2",
                "taskReferenceName": "Second Experiment",
                "inputParameters": {
                    "firstName": "Kirkland",
                    "lastName": "Yuknis"
                },
                "type": "SIMPLE",
                "startDelay": 30,
                "optional": false
            },
            {
                "name": "worker_3",
                "taskReferenceName": "Third experiment",
                "inputParameters": {
                    "firstName": "Kirkland",
                    "lastName": "Yuknis",
                    "vehicles": [
                        {"make": "Subaru", "model": "Outback", "trim": "Limited", "year": 2018},
                        {"make": "Subaru", "model": "Outback", "trim": "Limited", "year": 2018},
                        {"make": "Subaru", "model": "Outback", "trim": "Limited", "year": 2018}
                        ]
                },
                "type": "SIMPLE",
                "startDelay": 45,
                "optional": false
            }
        ],
        "schemaVersion": 2,
        "restartable": true,
        "workflowStatusListenerEnabled": false
    },
    "input": {}
}
```

Things seemed to work well for the first two experiments, but in the last one Conductor failed to execute the task. After reading the documentation, I'm wondering if it is possible to have a composed object as an input for a Conductor task. Is anyone able to confirm or deny this? If you can, where might I be going about it wrong?

**Worker output from `execute()` method when the server calls the worker**

```
The map's contents were:
{}

The objects's contents were:
Person{firstName='null', lastName='null', vehicles=null}

The map's contents were:
{firstName=Kirkland, lastName=Yuknis}

The objects's contents were:
Person{firstName='Kirkland', lastName='Yuknis', vehicles=null}
```

**Update: I just found the following error, which makes it look like a Jackson issue**

```
{
         "taskType": "worker_3",
         "status": "FAILED",
         "inputData": {
            "firstName": "Kirkland",
            "lastName": "Yuknis",
            "vehicles": [
               {
                  "make": "Subaru",
                  "model": "Outback",
                  "trim": "Limited",
                  "Year": 2018
               },
               {
                  "make": "Subaru",
                  "model": "Outback",
                  "trim": "Limited",
                  "Year": 2018
               },
               {
                  "make": "Subaru",
                  "model": "Outback",
                  "trim": "Limited",
                  "Year": 2018
               }
            ]
         },
         "referenceTaskName": "Third experiment",
         "retryCount": 0,
         "seq": 3,
         "pollCount": 1,
         "taskDefName": "worker_3",
         "scheduledTime": 1559838042119,
         "startTime": 1559838087887,
         "endTime": 1559838088012,
         "updateTime": 1559838087888,
         "startDelayInSeconds": 45,
         "retried": true,
         "executed": false,
         "callbackFromWorker": true,
         "responseTimeoutSeconds": 1200,
         "workflowInstanceId": "08a7bf21-6f4b-4265-97b0-0ce9cc93d1a4",
         "workflowType": "do_all_the_things_2",
         "taskId": "3b4906df-7136-4669-a8c8-a12a9b7c2f6a",
         "reasonForIncompletion": "Error while executing the task: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized field \"vehicles\" (class com.yuknis.egypt.models.Person), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: \"lastName\", \"firstName\"])\n at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.yuknis.egypt.models.Person[\"vehicles\"])",
         "callbackAfterSeconds": 0,
         "workerId": "Kirklands-MBP.hsd1.fl.comcast.net",
         "workflowTask": {
            "name": "worker_3",
            "taskReferenceName": "Third experiment",
            "inputParameters": {
               "firstName": "Kirkland",
               "lastName": "Yuknis",
               "vehicles": [
                  {
                     "make": "Subaru",
                     "model": "Outback",
                     "trim": "Limited",
                     "Year": 2018
                  },
                  {
                     "make": "Subaru",
                     "model": "Outback",
                     "trim": "Limited",
                     "Year": 2018
                  },
                  {
                     "make": "Subaru",
                     "model": "Outback",
                     "trim": "Limited",
                     "Year": 2018
                  }
               ]
            },
            "type": "SIMPLE",
            "startDelay": 45,
            "optional": false,
            "taskDefinition": {
               "createTime": 1559837812844,
               "name": "worker_3",
               "retryCount": 3,
               "timeoutSeconds": 0,
               "timeoutPolicy": "TIME_OUT_WF",
               "retryLogic": "FIXED",
               "retryDelaySeconds": 600,
               "responseTimeoutSeconds": 1200,
               "concurrentExecLimit": 100,
               "rateLimitPerFrequency": 50,
               "rateLimitFrequencyInSeconds": 60
            },
            "asyncComplete": false
         },
         "rateLimitPerFrequency": 0,
         "rateLimitFrequencyInSeconds": 0,
         "taskDefinition": {
            "present": true
         },
         "queueWaitTime": 45768,
         "taskStatus": "FAILED",
         "logs": [
            "06/06/19, 16:21:28:008 : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized field \"vehicles\" (class com.yuknis.egypt.models.Person), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: \"lastName\", \"firstName\"])\n at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.yuknis.egypt.models.Person[\"vehicles\"])\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:3750)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:3668)\n\tat com.yuknis.egypt.workers.ExperimentStepWorker.execute(ExperimentStepWorker.java:58)\n\tat com.netflix.conductor.client.task.WorkflowTaskCoordinator.execute(WorkflowTaskCoordinator.java:379)\n\tat com.netflix.conductor.client.task.WorkflowTaskCoordinator.lambda$pollForTask$4(WorkflowTaskCoordinator.java:340)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)\nCaused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field \"vehicles\" (class com.yuknis.egypt.models.Person), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: \"lastName\", \"firstName\"])\n at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.yuknis.egypt.models.Person[\"vehicles\"])\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:61)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:823)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1153)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1589)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1567)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:294)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:3745)\n\t... 9 more\n"
         ]
      },
```

Comment: Did you try "year" instead of "Year"?

Comment: I just tried right now. It still failed with the same error. I'll update the JSON payload in the question with the new one with the lowercase "y".

Comment: I found the problem. As a habit I do not create accessors for non-primitive data members on a class. Since `List<Vehicle>` is a non-primitive, I (without thinking) did not create accessors for it. In addition to this, `vehicles` was `protected` and not `public`. I've added the accessor and it solved the issue. Thanks all who looked at this!

Comment: Oh, I was going to ask about that, but this comment "// Constructors, getters, setters" made me think you had already all the accessors :)

Comment: I know, and tbh I was thinking I did. It's just a habit :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. As a habit I do not create accessors for non-primitive data members on a class. Since List is a non-primitive, I (without thinking) did not create accessors for it. In addition to this, vehicles was protected and not public. I've added the accessor and it solved the issue. Thanks all who looked at this!